# Rotating an image using mouse location - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner programmer and I am learning to code in college (UK) using VB.

I have a bitmap drawn in the centre of a picturebox which is an image of an arrow facing right. To rotate I'm using;

```
RAD = Math.Atan2(MOUSE_Y - CENTRE_Y, MOUSE_X - CENTRE_X) 
ANG = RAD * (180 / Math.PI)
```

And as you can see I'm trying to use MousePosition.Y & X to rotate the image using the mouse position so that the arrow points towards the mouse but the angle of the arrow is off since it's using the whole monitor size for the X and Y whereas I'd like it to use only the form size (which is 640x480)

Here is the Picturebox1_Paint sub;

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim MOUSE_X As Integer
    Dim MOUSE_Y As Integer
    Dim CENTRE_X As Integer
    Dim CENTRE_Y As Integer
    Dim BMP As Bitmap
    Dim ANG As Integer = 0
    Dim RAD As Double
    Dim GFX As Graphics = e.Graphics
    BMP = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ARROWE)

    MOUSE_X = (MousePosition.X)
    MOUSE_Y = (MousePosition.Y)
    CENTRE_X = PictureBox1.Location.X + PictureBox1.Width / 2
    CENTRE_Y = PictureBox1.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Height / 2

    RAD = Math.Atan2(MOUSE_Y - CENTRE_Y, MOUSE_X - CENTRE_X)
    ANG = RAD * (180 / Math.PI)

    GFX.TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Height / 2, PictureBox1.Width / 2)
    GFX.RotateTransform(ANG)
    GFX.DrawImage(BMP, -30, -30, 60, 60)
    GFX.ResetTransform()

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the mouse variables global outside the paint event and capture them in the form mousemove event:

```
Private MOUSE_X As Integer
Private MOUSE_Y As Integer

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    MOUSE_X = e.X
    MOUSE_Y = e.Y
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub    

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim CENTRE_X As Integer
    Dim CENTRE_Y As Integer
    Dim BMP As Bitmap
    Dim ANG As Integer = 0
    Dim RAD As Double
    Dim GFX As Graphics = e.Graphics
    BMP = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ARROWE)

    CENTRE_X = PictureBox1.Location.X + PictureBox1.Width / 2
    CENTRE_Y = PictureBox1.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Height / 2

    RAD = Math.Atan2(MOUSE_Y - CENTRE_Y, MOUSE_X - CENTRE_X)
    ANG = RAD * (180 / Math.PI)

    GFX.TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Height / 2, PictureBox1.Width / 2)
    GFX.RotateTransform(ANG)
    GFX.DrawImage(BMP, -30, -30, 60, 60)
    GFX.ResetTransform()

End Sub
```